# Como cargo ComboBox con una lista cargada [XAML][MVVM][UWP]

Tags: lista, xaml, uwp, binding

es que tengo un ComboBox en XAML y le tengo que hacer Binding al ViewModel para cargarlo con una consulta que hago de una tabla llamada "Ciudad" que tiene unos campos id, Nombre, Pais. pero en el combo solo me interesa mostrar la ciudad, creo que va asi pero no se que estoy haciendo mal, si hago la consulta se carga la lista, pero no el Combo.

Codigo Combo:

```
<ComboBox Header="Ciudad" Width="245" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Ciudades}" SelectedIndex="{Binding CountCiudad, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Las propiedades que tengo estan asi:

```
public List<Ciudad> Ciudades { get => ciudades; set => Set(ref ciudades, value); }
private List<Ciudad> ciudades;
```

y asi tengo el metodo:

```
public async void CargarCiudades(){
    this.Ciudades = new List<Ciudad>(await App.Repository.Ciudad.GetAsync());
}
```

No se por que no me carga, en el metodo la lista queda cargada, asi que no se si es en el XAML donde estoy fallando

Imagen del comportamiento del metodo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remueve esta parte del binging

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding CountCiudad, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Porque CountCiudad puede estar causando una excepción por IndexOutOfRange.

Y si la memoria no me falla la lista tiene que ser una observable collection

Comment: Ya lo quite, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Bien, revisa mis nuevos comentarios en el post porque creo que el problema es el tipo de lista

Comment: Listo ya lo solucione, resulta que en el ItemSource no es x:Bind si no Binding, el metodo lo deje igual, por que funciona, asi que el boton me quedo asi:            

<ComboBox Header="Ciudad" Width="245" ItemsSource="{Binding Ciudades}" x:Name="Combo_Ciudad">